# Move files in a list from one directory to another on FTP server

Tags: batch-file, ftp, copy

I have a directory on FTP server with 1000s of files. I would like to move 100 files from that directory to another directory on same FTP server. I have a list which contains the exact name of files that I want to move. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

Test this with some sample files: the filenames go in `filelist.txt` and `folder1` and `folder2` are the source and target folders.

```
@echo off
set "name=your_ftp_user-name"
set "password=your_ftp_password"
set "server=ftp_server_name"


set "ftpScript=%temp%\%~nx0.ftp.tmp"
(
    echo open %server%
    echo %name%
    echo %password%
    echo bin
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("filelist.txt") do 
      echo rename "\folder1\%%a" "\folder2\%%a"
    )
    echo quit
) > "%ftpScript%"

ftp -i -s:"%ftpScript%"
del       "%ftpScript%"
pause
```